# Describing neighborhoods in a Lie group with exponentials from Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $H$ and $K$  be a Lie subgroups of $G$ with Lie algebras $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ respectively, such that $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{k}.$

Consider a maximal torus $T$ of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$.We denote $N(T)= \lbrace g \in G, gTg^{-1}=T\rbrace $ the normalizer group. Let $\mathcal{F}=G/T$ be the flag manifold of $G$.

I'm reading a proof of a proposition and don't understand the following claims:

> A neighborhood of $x = gT \in \mathcal{F}$ is of the form $e^Xe^Yx$ where $X\in \mathfrak{h}$ and $Y \in \mathfrak{k}$.

and

> Suppose that  $e^{Y}$ belongs to $N(T).$ If $Y$ is sufficiently small, then $Y \in \mathfrak{t}.$

Any help please to understand why these claims are true!

**Edit** to be more precise my question about the first claim is the following: Did the author meant that every neighborhood of $x \in G/T$ is defined by elements of the form $e^Xe^Yx$ where $X \in \mathcal{h}$ and $Y \in \mathcal{k}$ ? and why ?

Comment: That first claim is sloppily written and also kinda wrong. First of all, the neighborhood is not of that form, but one should say it consists of elements of that form. Secondly, those are elements of $G$ and not $G/T$, so what's really meant are the images in the quotient. Most importantly, however, it's just wrong as stated. You might need to restrict $X$ and $Y$ to sufficiently small open balls around $0$ in the respective Lie algebras.

Comment: "those are elements  of  $G$ and not $G/T$" why ? They are of the form $e^Xe^Y x = e^X e^Y gT $.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit further in you sentence "You might need to restrict X and Y to sufficiently small open balls around 0 in the respective Lie algebras."

Comment: Actually, I might have to retract that. The phrasing is confusing me as to what is actually meant. The claim that any neighborhood is of the given form would be ridiculously false. If you look at the family of sets where you restrict $X$ and $Y$ to open balls in the respective Lie algebras, you obtain a neighborhood basis. If the claim is merely that that one particular set is a neighborhood of $x$, then it's fairly trivial and true (but that neighborhood need not be open).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Thorgott. Do you have any idea about the second claim ?